# php bool echo output

Tags: php

I have a strange problem.

If have function that does this return the value,

```
public function isVipCustomer($customer_id){
        $cus_vip_id=FALSE;
        $sql="SELECT customerid FROM customers WHERE is_vip='1' 
                AND customerid='".$customer_id."' LIMIT 0,1 ";  
        $result= $this->db->query($sql);

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $cus_vip_id=(int)$row['customerid'];    
        }

        if($cus_vip_id!=0)
            return TRUE;
        else
            return FALSE;

    }
```

when I call

```
$customer_id=13;
echo $collection->isVipCustomer($customer_id);
```

when its true it outputs 1 but when its false its empty, expecting a output of 0

why?

Comment: Directly entring variables into your query is bad and dangerous, check [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and parameters

Comment: Use `var_export($collection->isVipCustomer($customer_id))` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PHP documentation:

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is
>   converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and
>   forth between boolean and string values.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

To print the return value back with the type, try using `var_dump($myVar)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

When converting a boolean value to a string, `true` converts to `"1"` and `false` to `""` (an empty string).

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting

Your expectation is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what PHP does when converting bool to string.
Try this:

```
echo $collection->isVipCustomer($customer_id) ? 1 : 0;
```

Or if you just want to output something for debugging purposes and you want to have a clear sign of false, use this:

```
var_dump($collection->isVipCustomer($customer_id));
```

This will output `bool(true)` or `bool(false)`